# How to Use the SendKeys Statement to insert text into another application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am a beginner, and am using Visual Basic 2010 Express. I would like an example of how to use the SendKeys Statement to give key input into a game. I cant seem to find any answers after searching a half an hour or it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following links :

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyzLjMSvmJ0
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dff68c89-f520-40db-a570-ffc510808784/send-keys-to-dirctex-game
- http://vbcity.com/forums/t/119502.aspx